# How to write re-usable puppet definitions?

Tags: puppet

I'd like to write a puppet manifest to install and configure an application on target servers.

Parts of this manifest shall be re-usable. Thus I used `define` for defining my re-usable functionality. Doing so, I've always the problem that there are parts of the definition which are not re-usable.

A simple example is a bunch of configuration files to be created. These file must be placed in the same directory. This directory must be created only once.

Example:

**nodes.pp**

```
node 'myNode.in.a.domain' {
  mymodule::addconfig {'configfile1.xml':
    param => 'somevalue',
  }
  mymodule::addconfig {'configfile2.xml':
    param => 'someothervalue',
  }
}
```

**mymodule.pp**

```
define mymodule::addconfig ($param) {

  $config_dir = "/the/directory/"

  #ensure that directory exits:
  file { $config_dir:
    ensure  => directory,
  }

  #create the configuration file:     
  file { $name:
    path    => "${config_dir}/${name}"
    content => template('a_template.erb'),
    require => File[$config_dir],
  }
}
```

This example will *fail*, because now the resource `file {$config_dir:` is defined twice.

As far as I understood, it is required to extract these parts into a `class`. Then it looks like this:

**nodes.pp**

```
node 'myNode.in.a.domain' {

  class { 'mymodule::createConfigurationDirectory':
  }

  mymodule::addconfig {'configfile1.xml':
    param => 'somevalue',
    require => Class ['mymodule::createConfigurationDirectory'],
  }
  mymodule::addconfig {'configfile2.xml':
    param => 'someothervalue',
    require => Class ['mymodule::createConfigurationDirectory'],
  }
}
```

But this makes my interface hard use. Every user of my module has to know, that there is a class which is additionally required.
For this simple use case the additional class might be acceptable. But with growing module complexity (lots of definitions) I'm a bit afraid of confusing the modules user.

So I'd like to know is there a better way to handle this dependencies. Ideally, classes like `createConfigurationDirectory` are hidden from the user of the modules api.

Or are there some other "Best Practices"/Patterns handling such dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Break all the functionality into [separate files](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/style_guide.html#separate-files) within the module, each file containing one class or defined type. Use [resource](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html) [ordering](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_relationships.html) to manage resources in the correct order.

In your node definition:

```
class {'mymodule':
  conffile => 'file_name',
}
```

In your module manifest directory:

**init.pp:**

```
# This class does basic setup,
# and optionally allows you to define a config file
class mymodule ( $conffile = undef ) {
  include mymodule::confdir

  if $conffile {
    mymodule::conffile { $conffile: }
  }
}
```

**params.pp:**

```
# This class defines variables
class mymodule::params {
  $confdir = '/path/to/dir'
}
```

**confdir.pp:**

```
# This class creates a conf dir
class mymodule::confdir {
  include mymodule::params

  file { $mymodule::params::confdir:
    ensure = directory,
  }
}
```

**conffile.pp:**

```
# This define creates a config file
define mymodule::conffile($file=$title) {
  include mymodule::params

  file { "${mymodule::params::confdir}/${file}":
    ensure  => present,
    require => Class['mymodule::confdir'],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is best if you can take out the config directory from the define.
This is an example

```
class def($config_dir) {
    file { $config_dir:
        ensure => directory
     }   
}

define def::template($file_location) {
     file { $file_location:
         path    => "${def::config_dir}/${file_location}",
         content => 'hi',
         require => Class['def'],
     }   
 }
if $fqdn == 'my_host' {
    class { 'def':
            config_dir => '/tmp/d1'
        }   
    def::template { 'f1.txt':
        file_location => "f1.txt"
    }   
    def::template { 'f2.txt':
        file_location => "f2.txt"
    }   
}

ls  /tmp/d1/
f1.txt  f2.txt
```